Python error "RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after shutdown"
I am running a python (v3.9.16) application from a main thread while a separate worker thread runs an asyncio loop that makes SQL queries to a database (using aioodbc v0.5.0).
The main thread registers a shutdown function using atexit. When the main thread application issues a sys.exit, the shutdown function is called but does not have a chance to gracefully tear down the worker thread. Instead, the worker thread immediately continues processing any jobs (database queries) that were pending prior to the sys.exit, then the following error is thrown:
"RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after shutdown"
Note that I can't avoid using the main and worker threads, an asyncio loop in the worker thread and calling exit from the main thread.
Has anyone run into a similar problem? And if so, were you able to resolve the issue?
Any advice is greatly appreciated!

As a workaround to the above problem, I simply implemented a custom exit function that wraps my shutdown function followed by sys.exit. This allowed me to remove the problematic code of registering my shutdown function with atexit.
